# Redefining attribute about object property causes an error

Tags: javascript

The book, PROFESSIONAL JavaScript ® for Web Developers Third Edition, says:

> Additionally, once a property has been defi ned as nonconfigurable, it
>   cannot become configurable again. Any attempt to call
>   Object.defineProperty() and change any attribute other than writable
>   causes an error.

```js
'use strict';
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key',  {
  value:'static'
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key', {
  writable: true,
});
```

I write a code snippet above, but it throws an error.
The book says that I can redefine the writable attributes. Why does it cause an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it cause an error?

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> If a property is non-configurable, its `writable` attribute can only be changed to `false`.

So the statement in the book is not precise enough: You can change `writable` on a non-configurable property, but only from `true` to `false`, not the other way round, which is what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

A property can only be changed from non-writable to writable if its `configurable` attribute is true. ([ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) 7th ed., §6.1.7.1) By default, it's false.

If you want to configure metadata for the property after creating it, add `configurable: true` to the first `defineProperty`.

```js
'use strict';
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key',  {
  value:'static',
  configurable: true
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key', {
  writable: true,
});

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'key'));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you skip property descriptors in `Object.defineProperty`, they take on some default value instead.

In the case of the `writable` descriptor, the default value is `false`, which means not setting it the first time has the same effect as this:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key',  {
  value:'static',
  writable: false
});
```

If you explicitly set `writable` to `true` and rerun the code, you'll see that there is no exception thrown.

Comment: Well, to be fair, there is no exception because if `writable` is already `true`, it's not changed with second call. It's a noop.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's true. It still makes sense in contrast to the original example in the question though, as it shows that the problem originates in the first call. But you're right.